# Controllers in AngularJS and templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, design-patterns

I'm fairly new to AngularJS and I want to have the best practices from start. I want to know where should I put which controller I'll be using for a specific template. For now I've used this two:

**In the html of the template**

```
<div ng-controller="ImageManagerController"> </div>
```

**In my routes.js**

```
.state('home',{
    url : '/',
    templateUrl : '/src/images/views/home.html',
    controller : 'ImageManagerController'
})
```

Is one of them better than the other?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using `ng-controller` directive in HTML :**

- This scopes the controller to a specific element on the page/template. That can make the code easier to read when you need multiple controllers on a single page and it allows the controller to be more specifically scoped.
- New `$scope` object will created on `ng-controller`.
- visible with page source or inspect element.

**Controller in `Route` :**

- Allows you to specify a single controller for a template. Since this is part of the routing it makes it easy to find the controller that goes with the page. I use this to store and load overall page logic rather than element specific logic.
- New `$scope` object is created per route on the `ng-view`.
- Not visible with page source or inspect element.
- If you will use this `<div ng-view ng-controller="ImageManagerController">` then you'd need to change that controller as the route changed. So basically the router does that for you, and uses the controller you specified when you defined your routes.

I hope these differences will help you in deciding which to use.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I already switched to routes.js, I find it better for locating the controller based on route like @charlietfl said!

Comment: I don't believe last part is accurate. The `ng-controller` shown is not going to get a dynamic controller from router every time state changes

Answer (score 2):

When you do both you will create 2 instances of the controller, you don't want that

The biggest advantage of setting it in the routing config is that any related `resolve` will be made available for injection in the controller that is referenced.

Also when you have a lot of routes it is easy to look up which controller you would need to modify for any specific route when they are all listed in a config

Comment: I meant the 1st OR the second method, but when I first started, I used both and I noticed some logs being printed twice, but never knew why. Thank you!